# Twitter Streaming in Python: cp949 codec

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am currently using tweepy to gather data using Streaming API.

Here is my code and I ran this on Acaconda command prompt. When streaming starts, it returns tweets and then after giving few tweets it gives the following error:

```
Streaming Started ...
RT @ish10040: Crack Dealer Released Early From Prison By Obama Murders Woman And Her 2 Young Kids… Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jae Hee\Anaconda2\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Jae Hee\Anaconda2\lib\threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jae Hee\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 294, in _run
    raise exception
UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp949' codec can't encode character u'\xab' in position 31: illegal multibyte sequence
```

I believe that it has to do with encoding so I used chcp 65001 to deal with this issue but it does not give the solution!

Here is the code

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)


class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
      print(status.text)

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        #returning False in on_data disconnects the stream
        if status_code == 420:
            return False

def main():

    myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
    myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener = myStreamListener)


    print "Streaming Started ..."

    try:
        myStream.filter(track=['Obama'], async = True)
    except:
        print "error!"
        myStream.disconnect()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

All text produced and accepted through the twitter API should be encoded as UTF-8, so your code should be using that codec to decode what's coming back.

See here: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/counting-characters

Comment: for the track string I even tried using u'Obama' but still does not work. I know that I need to use UTF-8 so I did chcp 65001 but still does not work.